# APEX SOAP Callout - Need to add variable

Tags: apex, callout, soap

For some reason I'm struggling with this and I'm pretty familiar with XML, but I cannot seem to get this to work.
In the below section are several strings that ultimately make a request to get currency exchange rates.  In the string that shows the source currency I need to make is a variable that I can pass several different rates through.  Currently the line says $cur with several attempts to set a variable, but to no avail.
Does anyone know how to do this?
Ultimately what I'll be doing is looping through a list of companies, finding the home currency, using that as a variable and find the exchange rates for other currencies.

```
String xmlString = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:_1="http://">';
xmlString +='   <soapenv:Header>';
xmlString +='   <_1:RequestHeader>';
xmlString +='         <_1:correlationId></_1:correlationId>';
xmlString +='         <_1:clientApplicationName>TestApp</_1:clientApplicationName>';
xmlString +='     </_1:RequestHeader>';
xmlString +='   </soapenv:Header>';
xmlString +='   <soapenv:Body>';
xmlString +='      <_1:CurrencyConversionRequest>';
xmlString +='         <_1:ConversionRequestItems>';
xmlString +='            <!--0 to 200 repetitions:-->';
xmlString +='            <_1:dailyRateConversionRequest id="">';
xmlString +='               <_1:sourceAmount>1</_1:sourceAmount>';
xmlString +='               <!--Optional:-->';
xmlString +='               <_1:sourceCurrency>'+$cur+'</**_1:sourceCurrency>';
xmlString +='               <!--Optional:-->';
xmlString +='               <_1:dailyExchangeRateType>ES</_1:dailyExchangeRateType>';
xmlString +='               <!--Optional:-->';
xmlString +='               <_1:targetCurrency>EUR</_1:targetCurrency>';            
xmlString +='               <_1:rateDateBegin>2014-12-01T00:00:00</_1:rateDateBegin>';
xmlString +='               <!--Optional:-->';
xmlString +='               <_1:rateDateEnd>2014-12-01T00:00:00</_1:rateDateEnd>';
xmlString +='            </_1:dailyRateConversionRequest>';
xmlString +='          <!--0 to 200 repetitions:-->';
xmlString +='            <_1:periodicRateConversionRequest id="8bef7005-ecb1-49a8-881d-95b36eeca02f">';
xmlString +='               <_1:sourceAmount>1</_1:sourceAmount>';
xmlString +='               <!--Optional:-->';
xmlString +='               <_1:sourceCurrency>BRL</_1:sourceCurrency>';
xmlString +='           <_1:periodicExchangeRateType>H</_1:periodicExchangeRateType>';
xmlString +='               <!--Optional:-->';
xmlString +='               <_1:targetCurrency>USD</_1:targetCurrency>';       
xmlString +='               <_1:fiscalYear>2015</_1:fiscalYear>';
xmlString +='               <!--Optional:-->';
xmlString +='               <_1:fiscalQuarter>3</_1:fiscalQuarter>';      
xmlString +='            </_1:periodicRateConversionRequest>';
xmlString +='         </_1:ConversionRequestItems>';
xmlString +='      </_1:CurrencyConversionRequest>';
xmlString +='   </soapenv:Body>';
xmlString +='</soapenv:Envelope>';


Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
// url that returns the XML in the response body
req.setEndpoint('https:');
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
String username = '';
String password = '';
Blob headerValue = Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password);
String authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);

req.setBody(xmlString);
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

System.debug(res.getBody());

Dom.Document doc = new Dom.Document();
String xml = res.getBody();
XPath xp = new XPath(xml);
String rootPathCurrencyConversionResponse = '';
String PathdailyExchangeRateConversion = '';
String PathperiodicRateConversionResponse = '';

System.debug('**PathdailyExchangeRateConversion**');
// PathdailyExchangeRateConversion
For (Dom.XmlNode xmlt : xp.find(rootPathCurrencyConversionResponse + PathdailyExchangeRateConversion)[0].getChildElements())
{
    String xmlNodeName = xmlt.getName();
    String xmlNodeValue = xmlt.getText();
    System.debug(xmlNodeName + ' : ' + xmlNodeValue);
}

System.debug('**PathperiodicRateConversionResponse**');
// PathperiodicRateConversionResponse
For (Dom.XmlNode xmlt : xp.find(rootPathCurrencyConversionResponse + PathperiodicRateConversionResponse)[0].getChildElements())
{
    String xmlNodeName = xmlt.getName();
    String xmlNodeValue = xmlt.getText();
    System.debug(xmlNodeName + ' : ' + xmlNodeValue);
```

Comment: Use the `{}` button on code to make it readable in text. A screenshot is definitely less accessible.

Comment: Thank you -- found it and now it looks better

Answer (score 0):

$cur isn't a valid Apex identifier. There should be a for loop in here somewhere, I presume, but I don't see one. Further, you should be using the [Dom.Document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_xml_dom_document.htm) API to generate your XML code. This method of creating XML is error-prone and likely to cause you problems. Also, if this is a SOAP request, which it really looks like, consider using [WSDL2Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm) and using that to perform your callout. This drastically decreases the odds of messing up your code.

Comment: Yeah - I want to set it as a variable in some way so that I can do a loop through an object to change the requests.

Comment: @ElizabethShaw No, you should take the time to fix it. You'll eventually come to regret this method.